# Pass dockerPublisher maven properties over command line in spring-boot:build-image

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I want to integrate the spring boot maven plugins capability to build and publish an OCI Image to a remote Repository

## My Goal

I want to use the following plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <image>
      <name>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
    </image>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>build-image</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And now I want to pass the `docker.publishRegistry` variables by command line.

## What I've tried so far

I've tried to pass the parameter with the `-Ddocker.publishRegistry.username` property but that didn't work.

When you take a look at the source code of the plugin `Docker` has no Parameter property assigned to it:

```java
/**
 * Alias for {@link Image#publish} to support configuration via command-line property.
 */
@Parameter(property = "spring-boot.build-image.publish", readonly = true)
Boolean publish;

/**
 * Docker configuration options.
 * @since 2.4.0
 */
@Parameter
private Docker docker;
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/82b90d57496ba85be316b9eb88a36d81f2cc9baa/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/BuildImageMojo.java#L159

So I guess it is not possible to define this parameter by command line or is it?

## Current Workaround

Currently I'm defining the properties by global maven properties and reuse them in the `docker` scope.
My pom.xml:

```xml
<properties>
  <docker-registry>https://example.org</docker-registry>
  <docker-registry-username>username</docker-registry-username>
  <docker-registry-username>password</docker-registry-username>
</properties>
<!-- ... -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <image>
      <name>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
    </image>
    <docker>
      <publishRegistry>
        <username>${docker-registry-username}</username>
        <password>${docker-registry-password}</password>
        <url>${docker-registry}</url>
      </publishRegistry>
    </docker>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>build-image</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And I'm building with:

```sh
./mvnw -B -s \
  -Dspring-boot.build-image.publish=true \
  -Ddocker-registry-username="$USERNAME" \
  -Ddocker-registry-password="$PASSWORD" \
  -Ddocker-registry="$REGISTRY" \
  clean deploy
```

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem!

Answer (score 2):

I have not the exact solution to you question: "passing publishRegistry parameters on the command line", but If I may, I have another workaround that shields you from exposing your credential in the pom.xml.

What i have done is to put the parameters and credential in a profile in my `.m2/settings.xml` like this:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>docker-io-credentials</id>
            <properties>
                <docker-reg>docker.io</docker-reg>
                <docker-reg.user>your-user-name</docker-reg.user>
                <docker-reg.pwd>your-token-or-passwd</docker-reg.pwd>
                <docker-reg.url>${docker-reg}/library/${docker-reg.user}</docker-reg.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Then on the command-line you can simply pass the profile's name to merge the credential to the current build.

```
mvn clean install -Pdocker-io-credentials
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define placeholders in the spring-boot plugin's configuration, which refer to environment variables. This will be slightly less complex, so like

```
...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>main.Class</mainClass>
                <image>
                    <name>registry-url/library/image-name:${project.version}</name>
                </image>
                
                <docker>
                    <publishRegistry>
                        <username>docker-user</username>
                        <password>${env.docker_registry_password}</password>
                        <url>https://registry-url/v1/</url>
                        <email>user@example.com</email>
                    </publishRegistry>
                </docker>
            </configuration>
...
```

See more on this topic here: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-env-variables

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention that the Spring team is aware and did not consider this a bug but rather a documentation issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31024#issuecomment-1127905504

Very similar to what @twobiers suggested in his workaround:

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <docker>
        <publishRegistry>
            <url>${docker.publishRegistry.url}</url>
            <username>${docker.publishRegistry.username}</username>
            <password>${docker.publishRegistry.password}</password>
        </publishRegistry>
    </docker>
</configuration>
```

and then I build (and publish to Github Packages Registry) my project with:

```
./mvnw spring-boot:build-image \
  -Ddocker.publishRegistry.username=${{ github.actor }} \
  -Ddocker.publishRegistry.password=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} \
  -Ddocker.publishRegistry.url=ghcr.io \
  -Dspring-boot.build-image.publish=true \
  -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName="ghcr.io/${{ github.repository }}:latest" \
  -DskipTests
```